# How to build Dynamic Visitor Counter

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hitcounter

Hello guys I like to use fake dynamic visitor counter on my WooCommerce Store (WordPress) I like to add just below buy button so the counter like this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/Fsq43OY.gif]

In this example it sometimes decrease and sometimes increase completely dynamic.

I want the number to be run b/w 200-5000 so it wont increase beyond 5000 and neither decrease below 200 and not instant drop from 500-200 it should be slow and steady increase and decrease.

Comment: That's going to boost sales! No seriously. Why? Do you really think anyone cares about those counters? Just like hotel booking pages who claim "this hotel has been booked 5 times today". Yeah sure...

Comment: Those are annoying, but maybe they work on some folks. I see you have php and jquery tagged so you know basically what to use, so why not try something and come back when you have something show *(and are stuck)*.

Comment: I really think the question you're asking is great, but the use you make of it is not so great..

Comment: well @Andreas yeah it did boost sales and in very good way it would make your site some trending viral product store on which many users are getting in and when they would see stock decreasing that would trigger buy later behaviour to buy right now well it's all psychological thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using some JS you can pull that off. Use the `Math.random()` method and make the count change every n seconds with `setInterval()`.

```js
function random(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

var initial = random(500, 2000);
var count = initial;

setInterval(function() {
  var variation = random(-5,5);

  count += variation
  console.log('You currently have ' + count + ' visitors')

}, 2000)
```

You can change the variation (here it's between -5 and 5) and also the interval (here it's every 2 seconds).

Careful if you use JS, you can see the code in the source code... Have fun.

---

**EDIT**

Here's the code embedded in HTML, you can change `interval` (number of ms between two updates) and `variation` (how much the count can vary ±). You might want to change the `interval` to a higher value.

Bonus: some styling with CSS

```css
#counter-area {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(205, 204, 204, 0.19);
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#counter {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="counter-area">Real time <span id="counter"></span> visitors right now</div>
</body>

<script>
  function r(t,r){return Math.floor(Math.random()*(r-t+1)+t)}var interval=2e3,variation=5,c=r(500,2e3);$("#counter").text(c),setInterval(function(){var t=r(-variation,variation);c+=t,$("#counter").text(c)},interval);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: i like your counter but could you please make example how Schnatti created that would be really great of you!

Comment: "make example how Schnatti created" do you want me to explain his code?

Comment: his codes works for me but it's so much fake that from 1000-4000 it increase within second and and decrease like that too but with your example it works perfectly but if you can provide me in format like him that would be really greatful of you!
Ivan thing is that i am just noob in this thats why example of Schnatti works for me as it is having in html format with js included and execution tag too so i just need to copy but his visitor dynamic numbers doesnt make any sense user will catch very fast its fake but yours seems legit!
thanks

Comment: Look at my edit above, it does the job. If you find this answer helpful consider up voting or even accepting this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
           function setCounterValue() {
           var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5000 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000;
           $("div#counter").html("visitor "+random);
           setTimeout(function(){ setCounterValue(); }, 3000);
        }
        setCounterValue();
        setTimeout(function(){ setCounterValue(); }, 3000);      
      });    
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="counter"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even if this code may work. It's JavaScript. Anyone can read the code in plain text and see that the counter is fake. And that will hurt sales for sure when that comes out. I won't downvote but it's not a good idea.

Comment: @Schnatti i like your counter example but the counter looks so much fake anyone could get it 1092 visitors grows to 3121 in matter of seconds well its should make sense 10-20 visitors increase 2-3 decrease same format again for decreasing and increasing it should make some real counter not look completely fake.

Comment: @Mayank sharma define a global variable like "visitors", when the page ist loading define the value: use a random number between 1000 and 5000. In the function setCounterValue you create a random number between -10 and 10. This value you add  to the "visitors" and show the new "visitors" value ... Have a look at Ivan's answer, he already suggested this.